# How can I output a status bar to the console without interfering with append (>>)?

Tags: python, progress-bar, stdout

I have a script that simply outputs log events formatted in json to the screen line by line. One line equals one json log event. I usually simply append the results to a file to hold onto them when I need to (./script.py >> json.logs).

This script can take a while depending on the input, and I'd like to add a simple progress bar or number to the bottom of the console as it's working. However, I think this will also be written to the log file if I append like normal and I do not want that.

What is the normal way to approach printing something to the console that will not be appended to stdout or >>? *Also*, if I'm just simply printing the results to the screen instead of logging them to a file, I need the status bar to not make a mess in the screen as well (or rather, to only ever show at the bottom of the console screen).

Comment: Have a look at the tqdm library, it might suit you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `>>` will by default only pipe STDOUT to the file, so if you print to STDERR, it won't go to the log. For example:

```
import sys
print("something") # this will go to json.logs
print("something else", file=sys.stderr) # this won't go to json.logs unless you specifically tell it to
```

As for making the bar itself, either look at something like [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) or if you specifically want the bar to appear at the bottom of the window, you may have to roll your own solution with [curses](https://docs.python.org/3.5/howto/curses.html). Or just do something simple, like print one asterisk at a time.

Comment: Thanks. So I'm assuming this is safe to use this as long as I'll never need to actually use STDERR for errors?

Comment: That's correct. If you do ever need to do that, then you probably will want to rewrite the Python script to just do the logging itself. You can do something like `f = open("json.log", "wt")`, and then `print("something", file=f)`, or use one of the more robust logging modules available.

Comment: To keep the bar at the bottom, you will need to write all your messages using `tqdm.write()`, or use your own curse based solution.

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to use the stderr (`import sys; sys.stderr.write('the bar')` you could use `print ('barstuff', file=sys.stderr)` if you are using python3). This works fine if you want to save the stdout in a file while having the bar in the screen. To have the bar always at the bottom of the screen, looks like quite complicated: you should know what is the height of the screen and, I think, this could be almost impossible from python.

Probably, with some magic, you could be able to print the bar at the beginning of the screen and a given number of lines below it using the \r to rewrite on the old strings.

Comment: Thanks. I can at least start with this. I also asked this above: It should be safe to use this solution as long as I never need to actually use STDERR for real errors, right?

Comment: Yes! In case you want to trace errors, you could use a different file as a log.